# distutils does not recompile C extension modules

Tags: python, distutils

I'm trying to use distutils with a Python module that contains extensions written in C. The program code is housed on a Linux server, but I sometimes upload changes from a Windows machine using the file transfer program WinSCP (editing is done in Notepad++). I've noticed that distutils often does not notice these changes in the C code (i.e. `python setup.py build` does not trigger `gcc` if the code was previously compiled). A check of the C source code on the server shows that it really has been updated correctly. On the other hand, changing the code directly on the server using a text editor like `vim` always causes `python setup.py build` to recompile the changed files. Any idea why uploading changed files might not cause distutils to recompile them?

Thanks.

EDIT:
After investigating this further I am noticing the same problem if I just create a plain C program with a Makefile. Thus this problem does not look like it is a distutils problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the source for distutils and seeing how it enforces rebuilds it looks like it checks timestamps of files to determine whether a file is out of date or not.

Can you make sure the timestamp is changing when winscp is uploading the file? Otherwise it looks like the build command has a "force" option that forces a rebuild no matter what.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my original post and noted now that this problem also occurs with the make command, so this is not a distutils-only problem. Nonetheless, the force option does get the job done until I can figure out why the uploaded files are not triggering a compile.

Comment: Actually, this could still be a timestamp related issue. If I remember correctly, GNU make ends up checking the timestamp of the source file against the previously built object files. If the source file is found to be newer then it will enforce a rebuild. Do two things to figure this out--first check the timestamp via `ls -l` on the file before and after an scp upload and compare it with the timestamp of the built object files. Then try running a `touch` on the source file and see if the object files are rebuilt.